# 100 voters choose candidates

Tags: combinatorics

100 voters must vote exactly 3 candidates out of 5, but each candidate must be voted by at least one voter, otherwise he will be expelled.
In how many different ways can the 100 voters vote, so as to meet the condition?

My thoughts:
If we name the candidates $A, B, C, D, E$, there are $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways to select 3 candidates.
Of these 10 different ways, 99 voters can vote the same set, for example, set 1 (of the 10 different sets) with the same 3 candidates and the 100th must vote another set with the 2 remaining candidates, and so on.
Of the possible 10 sets, each candidate appears in 6, so, in order for all candidates to be voted at least once, each voter must select 2 candidates out of 4, plus 1 candidate out of 6. That is, $\binom{4}{2} = 6 * \binom{6}{1} = 6$, total 36.
Therefore there are 36 different voting schemes.

Each of the 100 voters can select any of these 36 and of course we can have multiple of the same.

The rest is stars and bars: 100 distinct voters to select 1 of 36 distinct sets but I am not sure how to do it.

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: My first thought would be inclusion exclusion.  After all, in the worst case, there are two candidates who get eliminated, so you don't need to go through many levels.

Comment: @lulu, thank you for your comment; inclusion-exclusion, how?

Comment: Subtract off the cases where one specified candidate is eliminated.  Add back the cases where two specified candidates are eliminated.  The posted solution from @RobertShore does it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were no constraints, each voter would have $10$ choices of triplets to choose so since there are $100$ voters, there would be $10^{100}$ different possible ways for the voters to vote.

But there are constraints.  Suppose that all of the voters were choosing among $4$ rather than $5$ candidates.  There are $5$ choices of candidates to omit.  Once that choice is made, each voter would have $4$ choices so there would be $4^{100}$ ways for the voters to vote.

You might think, then, that there are $10^{100}-5 \cdot 4^{100}$ ways for the voters to vote and satisfy the constraints.  But this is where the principle of inclusion and exclusion comes in.  We've subtracted off too many combinations because we have double-counted the combinations where (for example) none of the voters choose either $A$ or $B$.

So how many ways are there for the voters to choose among $3$ candidates?  There are $\binom 52=10$ ways to choose the $2$ excluded candidates, and once we know them, each voter has only $1$ choice.

The final answer, therefore, is $10^{100}-5 \cdot 4^{100}+10$.